# Rewrite list of words to index.php

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite a few urls to the same page. Is there an easy way of rewriteing the following urls to index.php:

```
www.test.com/miami.html
www.test.com/chicago.html
www.test.com/boston.html
```

and rewrite them to

```
www.test.com/index.php
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is going in your .htaccess, if you're wanting an external rewrite (i.e. changing the browser URL):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(miami|chicago|boston)\.html$ index.php [R,NC,L]
```

If you're wanting an internal rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(miami|chicago|boston)\.html$ index.php [NC,L]
```

These assume you have the rewrite module enabled in the main config:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for